# Execute something when locking AND unlocking swaylock

Tags: archlinux, wayland

i want to be able to execute code when swaylock gets locked and something different when unlocking (eg swaylock was locked and i entered my password correctly). everything i found is a way to execute code after swaylock gets locked, which is possible with:

```sh
swaylock -f;somethingToExecute
```

the `-f` means "daemonize", this is the reaason why `...;somethingToExecute` gets execute after locking the session. The other way around is the same without daemonizing the process, so everything behind the `;` will be executed after swaylock exited (which means "the session is unlocked" because the swaylock-process is running as long as the session is locked).

But what if i want to execute code when locking AND unlocking the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...Sometimes one is just thinking way too complicated. In fact the answer is already inside the question:

```
somethingToExecuteWhenLocking; swaylock; somethingToExecuteWhenUnlocking
```